# Plotting a region with polar axes

Tags: plotting, regions

I'd want to plot the region of points which satisfy the following equation:

```
2 < r <= 5 && 3/4 π < θ <= 5/4 π
```

I have been able to plot the region in Cartesian coordinates:

```
h[r_, θ_] := 2 < r <= 5 && 3/4 π < θ < 5/4 π
RegionPlot[h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

I would like to plot the region with polar axes, but I don't think I can make `PolarPlot` plot a region probably.

Comment: As mentioned in the [PolarPlot docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html) (Properties & Relations section), PolarPlot is a special case of ParametricPlot for curves, and (though perhaps unsuitable for your application), you can plot regions with ParametricPlot, e.g. `ParametricPlot[r {θ Cos[θ], θ Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 4 Pi}, {r, 1, 1.5}, Mesh -> False]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update**

Compare two pictures. First is able to make mistake like you made the code.

[image: Blockquote]

You need to do like this code using `Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2π]`.

```
h[r_,θ_] := 2 < r <= 5 && 3/4 π < θ < 3/2 π
RegionPlot[
 h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2π]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

So I suggest to use `ParametricPlot` like this.

```
rg = 6; mg = 3;

ParametricPlot[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]}, {r, 2, 5}, {θ, 3/4 π, 5/4 π},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> False,
 PlotRange -> {-rg - mg, rg + mg},
 Epilog -> PolarPlot[rg, {θ, 0, $MachineEpsilon}, 
    PolarAxes -> True,
    PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, Range[rg]},
    PolarTicks -> {Drop[Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}], -1], 
      Automatic}][[1]]
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

**Origin**

This is my trick. I used option `Epilog`.

```
RegionPlot[
 h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 30,
 Epilog -> PolarPlot[5, {\[Theta], 0, $MachineEpsilon},
    PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}][[1]]
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And I tried also `PolarTicks` like this.

```
PolarTicks -> {Drop[Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}], -1], Automatic}
```

> [image]

**`PolarGridLines` Usage**

```
RegionPlot[
 h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 30,
 Epilog -> PolarPlot[6, {\[Theta], 0, $MachineEpsilon},
    PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, Range[6]},
    PolarTicks -> {Drop[Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}], -1], 
      Automatic}][[1]]
 ]
```

> [image]

Comment: How can I get coordinates from 0 to 6 instead of 0 to 5? Changing the 5 in `PolarPlot` to 6 produces this graphic, where the region isn't correct: http://i.imgur.com/7HYupnR.png

Comment: Modify the ticks numbers. If you make number 6 of the ticks then it looks good for that.

Comment: I tried `RegionPlot[h[Sqrt[x^2+y^2],ArcTan[x,y]],{x,-6,6},{y,-6,6},Frame->False,PlotPoints->30,Epilog->PolarPlot[6,{\[Theta],0,$MachineEpsilon},PolarAxes->True,PolarGridLines->Automatic,PolarTicks->{"Degrees",Range[0,6]}][[1]]]` which doesn't work. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Tyilo Sorry, Use option `PolarGridLines` like posted upper adding one.